# Importing multiple modules at parallel in python(using multiprocessing)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-import, python-module

I wanted to know if there is a way to import multiple modules at parallel using python, to decrease the load time of the app.

any help would be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible

Comment: As far as importing, there are methods to speed it up but they are strenuous and not worth the headache, I don't believe you can load them in parallel however.

Comment: If you use multiprocessing, you'll load the modules in *separate processes*.  That would make no sense.  And multithreading can't run Python code using true parallelism due to the global interpreter lock.  So no, it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

In python there is a module called Threading. It does so you can execute code in parallel. For example if you have a server with treading, then it can calculate and manage all the clients in parallel.

Comment: @Amal, no, due to the global interpreter lock in Python, Only one thread can run Python code at a time.  Threading is useful for I/O-bound work only.